# Can't change position of buttons in C# ASP.net

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I use VS 2010 . I add button to webfrom that created, but I can't change his position.
I read in previous questions that I need to change the layout to absolute , but it didn't work. when I drag the button to the center it's back automatically to left-center..
you can see that in the picture:

[image]

how can I fix that?

Thank you!!

---

solution:
Tools -> Options, and set HTML Designer -> CSS Styling to "Change positioning to absolute.."

Comment: Stop using the designer view. Just add CSS to center it.

Comment: I know that I can change the position with html \CSS code.
but in VS2008 it's worked fine with drag and drop.. that's what I want.

Comment: It's been a while since I used the grid layout feature which used to support what you're talking about...I don't know if the designer even supports this anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the position to absolute seems more like a workaround which would introduce further problems after "solving" this one.  Unless you *really* know what you're doing for styling, don't do that.

Centering an element on a webpage is really a matter for the CSS styling.  Take a look at the markup (HTML) view and find where that button is.  You can add a class to that button for the CSS styling:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="Button1" CssClass="centeredButton" ...
```

Then in your site's CSS file (Site.css might be the standard in the ASP.NET template?  I don't remember) you can apply the styling you're looking for.  There's a *lot* you can do at that point.  Not knowing how the rest of the page is laid out, I can only offer very random suggestions.  Something [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/mUwNS/) for example:

```
.centeredButton {
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
}
```

That's *one way* to center that particular element.  There are definitely more, depending on how the rest of the markup/layout is structured.

Answer (score 0):

First of all i recommend not to use this drag options. Because what happens behind this whenever you drag a button or anything, will make you more confused. You can do it using div or table.